# How to check for empty RDD in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, rdd

```
tweetStream.foreachRDD((rdd, time) => {
  val count = rdd.count()
  if (count > 0) {
    var fileName =  outputDirectory + "/tweets_" + time.milliseconds.toString    
    val outputRDD = rdd.repartition(partitionsEachInterval) 
    outputRDD.saveAsTextFile(fileName) 
}
```

I am trying to check count value or empty RDD in stream data in python way , hardy finding ways, also tried examples from the below link.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html

Answer (score 5):

[`RDD.isEmpty`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.isEmpty):

> Returns true if and only if the RDD contains no elements at all.

```py
sc.range(0, 0).isEmpty()
```

```
True
```

```py
sc.range(0, 1).isEmpty()
```

```
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`RDD.isEmpty`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.isEmpty) as user6910411 suggested:

```
df.rdd.isEmpty()
```

It returns boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following snippet of code.

```
def process_rdd(rdd):
    print rdd.count()
    print("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$")
    streamrdd_to_df(rdd)

def empty_rdd():
    print "###The current RDD is empty. Wait for the next complete RDD ###"

clean.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: empty_rdd() if rdd.count() == 0 else process_rdd(rdd))
```

Comment: please format your answer, to improve quality.. especially add code blocks.

Comment: What's "clean" here ?